# why tabBar.rx.didSelectItem didn't emit tap event?

Tags: swift, event-handling, uikit

[image]

when I tap the tabBarItem "Bookmarks" , I
**expect** below code block  will print : "select tabbar item" ,and don't print "root view tapped " .
but **actually** console prints "root view tapped " .  Can somebody tell me **why** it didn't work as I expected and how to fix it ?

by the way , I did asked chatGPT , but didn't get the right answer.

below is the complete code

```swift
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa


class TabBarViewController: UIViewController {
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // create a UITabBar 
        let tabBar = UITabBar()
        self.view.addSubview(tabBar)
        tabBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tabBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tabBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        let item1 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarItem.SystemItem.bookmarks, tag: 1)
        let item2 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarItem.SystemItem.contacts, tag: 2)
        tabBar.items = [item1, item2]
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(tabBar)
        
        // create a red container view
        let red = UIView()
        red.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(red)
        red.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        red.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        red.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        red.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.topAnchor).isActive = true
        red.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        
        
        
        tabBar.rx.didSelectItem.subscribe(onNext: { e in
            print("select tabbar item ")
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        
        red.rx.tapGesture()
            .when(.recognized)
            .subscribe { ele in
                print("red tapped")
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        
        view.rx.tapGesture(configuration: { tapGestureRecognizer, delegate in
            delegate.simultaneousRecognitionPolicy = .never
        })
        .when(.recognized)
        .subscribe(onNext: { ele in
            print("root view tapped ")
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: I had figure it out . tap recognizer in superview has recognized successfully , so the UIEvent would not propagate to UITabBar .that's why UITabBar didn't  print : "select tabbar item"

Answer (score 0):

I had figure it out . tap recognizer in superview has recognized successfully , so the UIEvent would not propagate to UITabBar .that's why UITabBar didn't print : "select tabbar item"

refer from official document :

> A window delivers touch events to a gesture recognizer before it delivers them to the hit-tested view attached to the gesture recognizer. Generally, if a gesture recognizer analyzes the stream of touches in a multi-touch sequence and doesn’t recognize its gesture, the view receives the full complement of touches. If a gesture recognizer recognizes its gesture, the remaining touches for the view are cancelled.The usual sequence of actions in gesture recognition follows a path determined by default values of the cancelsTouchesInView, delaysTouchesBegan, delaysTouchesEnded properties.